# How does a helper method yield to a block in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have used this pattern for a number of helpers in rails 2, but it isn't working the same in rails 3. My goal is to have a helper method generate some html tags with content nested inside. Here is a basic example of what I'm trying to get:

```
<div class="box">
  my content
</div>
```

In rails 2 I do it like this:

inside my layout file I call the helper method:

```
  <% box_wrapper do %>
    <%= yield -%>
  <% end %>
```

The helper method is defined like this:

```
def box_wrapper
  concat <<-EOF.html_safe
    <div class="box">
  EOF

  yield  if block_given?
  concat <<-EOF.html_safe
    </div>
  EOF
end
```

But in rails 3 when the view gets rendered it outputs my entire page and then inside the `box_wrapper` it renders all of the page content a 2nd time.

I think I'm missing something obvious with how to use helpers and yields. Any ideas?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In Rails 3, you no longer need to use the `concat` method to build the content of your blocks.

Your helper now looks like this:

```
def box_wrapper(&block)  
  content = capture(&block)  
  content_tag(:div, content, :class => 'box')  
end
```

You can see other examples in [Railscasts 208](http://railscasts.com/episodes/208-erb-blocks-in-rails-3).

Comment: just forwarding the recommendation of R. Bates: "UPDATE: I recommend using the “capture” method instead of “with_output_buffer”. This has the added benefit of working outside of ERB views. Code below has been updated."

Comment: @apneadiving - Thanks for that, definitely an improvement.

Comment: Thanks! My real use is more complicated than a plain content_tag, but that was enough to get me started.

Comment: @DouglasFShearer Just wondering why the need to call `capture(&block)` instead of `yield`. `yield` will actually end up rendering the view until that point.

Comment: @Dex also wondering this, but it seems yield sometimes doesn't.... yield the correct results in a case like this. `capture` is the way to go. Which is strange, because I have a similar use case in two helpers – in the first one I used `yield`, but in the other one this didn't work, and I needed to use `capture`